# mapbox direction api wrong route in ios

Tags: ios, swift, api, mapbox

I am using MapBox (Direction API) for drawing routes between two points. When I draw a root on the map on the Mapbox site I got the correct route, however when I use MapboxDirection API (MapboxDirections.swift) ON iOS I got a wrong route (it simply shortcuts the route instead of a turn. 
URL: https://api.mapbox.com/v4/directions/mapbox.driving/58.3492489633563,37.898002422381;58.3578,37.8787.json?access_token=pk.****&alternatives=true&geometry=polyline

```
directions!.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler { (response, error) in
                if let route = response?.routes.first {
                    print("Route summary:")
                    let steps = route.legs.first!.steps

                    print("Distance: \(route.distance) meters (\(steps.count) route steps) in \(route.expectedTravelTime / 60) minutes")
                    for step in steps {
                        print("\(step.instructions) \(step.distance) meters")

                        self.calculatedTour.append(step)
                        self.calculatedTourPoints.append(step.maneuverLocation)
                    }
                    self.tourLine = MGLPolyline(coordinates: &self.calculatedTourPoints, count: UInt(self.calculatedTour.count))

                    self.mapView.addAnnotation(self.tourLine)
                } else {
                    print("Error calculating directions: \(error)")
                }
            }
```

mapbox site:
[image]

in my app:
[image]

Comment: i guess it is returning the shortest route between two locations?considering automobile

Comment: no, there is no way.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? i still have it

Comment: @TheRedFox yes, i solved it.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/orazz/50e337754bcff979e8aa5ae4a8b09fd4#file-mapbox-calculate-directions

Comment: @orazz Could you please suggest how did you resolve it? Seems like I am having the same problem.

Comment: @RohitKumar [mapbox calculate directions](https://gist.github.com/orazz/50e337754bcff979e8aa5ae4a8b09fd4#file-mapbox-calculate-directions)

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be an unintentional over-simplification of the route.

[MapboxDirections.swift](https://github.com/mapbox/MapboxDirections.swift) `master` renders this route correctly, however:

[image]

Comment: Well, it _probably_ renders the route correctly — a longer route with more points will be subject to more simplification.

Comment: i'm facing this issue in mapbox latest sdk, Directions method not returning wrong routes some times

Answer (score 0):

the problem has been resolved

```
 for geoCoordinates in route.geometry {
       self.calculatedTourPoints.append(geoCoordinates)
   }
```